# Where do I cache media for a UITableView? What design pattern should I use?

Tags: ios, uitableview, caching, video, mp4

I'm a new iOS developer pretty far in to my first app.

I have a UITableView that displays a lot of data, with small videos in the Section Headers.  Right now in my builds I am embedding the videos in the app, but I'd like them to actually be fetched from a server since it takes too much space.

However, I'm not sure what kind of design pattern to use here.  The section headers aren't allocated until they come on screen obviously.  If I download the data in the background, and the user scrolls down to the section too early and doesn't get a video, and then the video finishes downloading in the background...how do I tell the TableView to now show the video?

Also, if I don't want to have to redownload approximately 3-4 MB of video every time the user loads up the tableview, what's the best way to actually save the videos somewhere (and delete them on application quit)?  So, when the user loads the UITableView, it'll download those videos, cache them, and remove them once the user is no longer needs them?

My first instinct is to have a background thread saving the videos to a special location in the user's documents that is purged on application quit, and run [self.tableview reloadData] every single time one of the videos (each about 200kb) finishes downloading, but I don't know if doing ~20 tableview reloads will impact performance or the user's view (and does reloadData release and reload the section header that is on screen?).

Really appreciate any advice as to how to do this correctly.

Comment: This is not a simple question to answer. 1. You need to write the code to handle how many concurrent downloads you want to happen, which can change based on the scroll velocity that the tableview is experiencing. 2. Cached data is stored in `NSURLCache` and `NSCachedURLResponse`, but, it's volatile and can be released if resources are low, meaning you'll need to decide when to save it locally (Core Data, or other). 3. Performance impact in this case is determined by your concurrent tasks, again. You can have a background operation that runs 10 concurrent operations and then updates the UI

Comment: on the main thread only when the task is completed. So the user doesn't experience any indication of performance issues.. but then again if you have too many network requests and tasks, they will see a slow down somewhere. Generally, you place a placeholder that gets replaced by the actual content when it's done downloading. You are notified of the complete download via something like callback blocks, or NSNotifications. And again, this design is all determined by how familiar you are with queues and network requests.

Comment: Some resources that might be helpful:[Explanation of NSURLCache](http://catthoughts.ghost.io/in-depth-nsurlcache/),   [NSURLSession tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial), [AFNetworking Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial), [Common Background Processes](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html), and [Using NSOperationQueues](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)